# How to get .grid_columnconfigure() working inside Frame using grid-Manager?

Tags: python, tkinter

I already asked this question, but got answers only for pack-Manager.

I want to create a GUI with tkinter in python using grid-Method and grid_columnconfigure/grid_rowconfigure. Unfortunately, this is not working inside a Frame.

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.state('zoomed')
f = Frame(master, width=800, height=400)

Label1 = Label(f, text='Label 1')
Label2 = Label(f, text='Label 2')

f.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
f.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
f.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight=1)

Label1.grid(row=0, column=1)
Label2.grid(row=0, column=3)

master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
master.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
master.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
f.grid(row=1, column=1)

master.mainloop()
```

I expected to have space between the two labels, but this is not working, because Frame is not taking more space inside master. How can I do this?

Comment: sorry for this, edited the question

Comment: put labels directly in master and remove Frame and you should get expected result. Or simply use `pack()` instead of bothering of grid()

Comment: for `master` you should set `weight=1` rather for column 1 and row 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me - but it would be easier to use `pack()`

---

Frame will not change size to Labels size:

```
f.grid_propagate(False)
```

Column and row in which is Frame will use all space (because there are not other columns and rows)

```
master.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
master.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

Frame will resize to column and row size (which already use all space in window)

```
f.grid(..., sticky='news')
```

---

To test code I added background colors - it shows me real size of widgets.

---

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master['bg'] = 'red'

master.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
master.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

f = Frame(master, width=400, height=300)
f.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='news')

f.grid_propagate(False)

f.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
f.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
f.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight=1)

l1 = Label(f, text='Label 1', bg='green')
l2 = Label(f, text='Label 2', bg='green')

l1.grid(row=0, column=1)
l2.grid(row=0, column=3)

master.mainloop()
```

---

If you remove `width=400, height=300` then window will have no size at start.